# CSS Text Alignment Issue

Tags: css, margin, padding

In Chrome and Safari, the following CSS problem occurs:

`ul`, `li` and `a` or link have a default CSS property that pushes everything vertically away. I have fiddled with the following properties:

```
font-size
margin-right
padding
color
text-decoration
margin
padding
border
display
list-style
vertical-align
line-height
line-height
font-style
margin
font-variant
padding-top
padding-bottom
margin-top
margin-bottom
```

And nothing seems to prevent the problem.
I've downloaded the CSS reset by Yahoo, but I'm unsure how to use it properly.
I haven't pursued that because I don't know that it would solve my problem anyway.

Comment: Please include a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code

Comment: Additionally, what values have you tried for the listed properties?  I've found that simply setting margin:0 and padding: 0 on "body *" takes care of any spacing issues (vertical or horizontal).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SBnKw/

Comment: Not sure how long the fiddle I posted lasts, but you said to post it and that's what I've done :)

Comment: I've looked at your fiddle, but I don't see what's wrong.  Your links don't seem to be pushing anything away vertically.  Unless you mean that they're on separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBnKw/) and I'm slightly confused.  You say things are being pushed away vertically, but I don't see that happening at all.

The only thing I see which could even somewhat meet that description is the fact that your links are on separate lines.

If this is the problem, the solution very simple: `div`s  are block-level elements.  This means that they default to 100% width and are designed to break onto a new line before they start, and onto a new line after.  This is the behavior of `display: block;` and is built-in to the default styles of a div.

To fix this, apply the following style:

```
#headernav div{ display: inline; }
```

This, however, is the least of your problems.  The code you copied into the fiddle lacks a closing tag for one of the div elements, which could cause unpredictable behavior in older browsers.  You have two divs with the same ID, which is a major no-no.

In [this update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBnKw/1/) I have fixed the HTML problems you have.  Note that 'tempLink' is now a class, and is targetted by a '.' in CSS, not the '#' that indicates an ID.

I have applied the above CSS to the class tempLink, instead of any div within your headernav.

Note in that fiddle that your two links are now side-by-side.  You can control the horizontal spacing between them with margin and padding (target the tempLink class).

Comment: I'm also very confused, and sometimes it's best just to move on. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrift mentioned it would be a lot easier to diagnose if you use jsFiddle. That being said, have you tried display: inline-block or float: left?

Comment: I've posted the awaited fiddle, and am in need of some assistance as neither of those properties have worked.